Intellij drag and drop
is it possible to drag and drop in IntelliJ without using hard code to fix?
I tried to drag and drop in intellij but I still adjust the size using hard code. what I want is like drag and drop in netbeans, is that possible?

Could you be a bit more specific? What are you trying to drag and drop? To where? What do yo actually mean by "hard code"? And what behavior do you expect, exactly ?

Drag and drop what? Adjusting the size and hard coding what? It's really not clear what you're asking.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
